# how to use asp.net Identity 2.0 with old database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I saw a lot toturial about asp.net Identity 2.0 with esixting database, but they still use the same table name(AspNetUsers) and column name, and some of column I don't wanna use, so I just want to implement IUser, I don't need to inherit the IdentityUser, and I just need 3 table (User, Roles, UserRole).

how do I use the asp.net Identity 2.0 with the old customized database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible. There are basically two options if you are using Entity Framework for your existing database.

1. Provide your own mapping to the built in classes, by using your own `OnModelCreating` override on the DB Context.
2. Provide an own storage for ASP.NET Identity by implementing `IUserStore`, `IRoleStore` and `IUserRoleStore` in one storage class. This way you can map to existing classes in your data model.

If you are using another DB access than EF Code First you have to use option 2

Comment: seems like using FormAuthentication is more easier in my case?

Comment: No, I don't think Forms Auth would make it easier. The extra work with ASP.NET Identity is to map it to your own DB - which isn't even possible with the old membership system. Not to mention that the password hashing of the older membership systems is no longer considered secure.